# Trouble figuring out how to add a custom view above WebView within the same ScrollView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I'm trying to create an app that will have an interface similar to the Mail app on the iPhone. When you view an email message on the built-in Mail app, it displays sender/receiver information in addition to the subject in an area before the message. I was thinking of using a WebView for the message portion, but I can't figure out a way to have some custom view appear above the WebView while still within the same ScrollView.

What is the best way to implement this? To me the best option seems to be generating the "custom view" at the top in HTML/CSS, and simply appending the message's HTML afterward. I've looked at trying to put a WebView with another view inside a ScrollView, but it seems to go against Apple's design guidelines.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: I'm a little confused. You're saying you want two subviews within a scrollview?

Comment: Yes, preferably I'd have some custom view at the top and a web view just below it. I want the custom view to scroll with the web view, however; I don't want to be able to scroll through the web view while still being able to see the custom view up top.

Comment: I'd say just don't use a webView and set the scrollView contentSize to the width of said views then the height to the sum of the heights of customView and messageView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't hink it is against Apple guidelines.

What I'd do in your case is the following.

First create the scroll view

Place inside it your fixed height header (with subject, etc...)

Then place inside the scrollview a webView with an y offset of your headers height.

After the webView is done loading call `[webView sizeToFit];` (wich resizes the view trying not to crop subViews)

Maybe you'll have to set the y offset again (`frame.origin.y=offset`)

And then set the scrollview content size to the sum of the two heights:

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width, headerView.frame.size.height + webview.frame.size.height);
```

I'm not really confident with what `[webView sizeToFit]` is going to do. I've read you can also use `[webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];` . It will apparently return the needed size for the webView.

The you would simply have to change the webviews frame size to the return value of that function and use the same contentsize statement as before.

Hope this helped

PS: I think it's a bad idea to use html as a replacement for views. It's much slower and it takes initial time to load. The only use I've found to it is for displaying formatted text.